# compare rows based on the value of some columns and update the table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains 5 columns,for example:

```
 f_id          s_id         t_id        string        date
  1             2            3          aaa_C       15/03/2008 10:30:00
  1             2            4          vvv_C       15/03/2008 10:30:00
  1             2            4          sss_C       15/03/2008 20:00:00
  1             2            3          xxx_B       15/03/2008 10:30:00
  1             2            5          yay_B       15/03/2008 10:30:00
```

I'm trying to compare rows to check if:

```
row1.f_id = row2.f_id = row3.f_id....and row1.s_id = row2.s_id = row3.s_id...
and row1.date = row2.date = row3.date..and row1.string like '%_samesuffix' and row2.string like '%_samesuffix'...
```

Then the output should be like this:

```
f_id          s_id         t_id        string        date
  1             2            3           C          15/03/2008 10:30:00
  1             2            4          sss_C       15/03/2008 20:00:00
  1             2            5           B          15/03/2008 10:30:00
```

I will be grateful for any hints.

Comment: I don't get it.  Why does the string column change?

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your expected output.

Comment: Each string refers a type (vvv, aaa or sss) of a specific product (the suffix e.g C).I would like to keep the product regardless of the type.So when I delete the target row( that matches the conditions), that does not mean that the type aaa is most important than vvv.